If we accept both "Deus otiosus" and Aquinas's "the First Cause" argument for existence of God, then would it imply in-Universe determinism?
Summary of the argument from Wikipedia:

In the world, we can see that things are caused. But it is not possible for something to be the cause of itself because this would entail that it exists prior to itself, which is a contradiction. If that by which it is caused is itself caused, then it too must have a cause. But this cannot be an infinitely long chain, so, there must be a cause which is not itself caused by anything further. This everyone understands to be God.

"Deus otiosus" is a belief that God doesn't interfere with the world after its creation. To elaborate, here I assume that God caused the Big Bang, simply set things in motion and now (maybe) watches how things unfold without any further interference. (Technically this is not what Christianity endorses, but the argument of "the first cause" seems to be compatible with "Deus otiosus" and other non-Christian viewpoints. )
By in-Universe determinism (or just determinism) in this question I mean a view that all things in our universe are determined. God is not considered to be a part of our Universe, thus question if God himself is determined is irrelevant.
In other words, can we both accept "the first cause" argument AND "Deus otiosus" without also accepting truth of determinism? At the least for me this argument (combined with "Deus otiosus", as to avoid direct divine creation of agents with free will and things caused by divine miracles) seems to assume that everything (except God) has its own cause, thus assuming determinism.
P.S. In my view we still have determinism even if we say that God has free will, as we still have reasons to worry about existence of free will for humans if we to accept combination of the first cause argument with "Deus otiosus". Thus for purpose of this question we don't say "Actually, we have no determinism because God has free will!".
P.P.S.  In my view, the argument basically says "Our world is just one long chain of falling dominoes. And we know that anything in our universe must be caused. And said chain of dominoes has its first domino. Then there is something outside our world, something supernatural, which caused the very first domino to fall". Under such view, it seems natural that without additional divine intervention "dominoes" will continue falling in the way they were set to fall, i.e. (in-Universe) determinism.

It sounds to me like maybe the question might be better phrased, "Does a closed universe imply determinism", rather than "Does the First Cause argument imply determinism"; i.e., I'm if we exclude human free will and divine intervention, I'm not really sure the First Cause argument has much to do with the implication.

@PeterRankin What do you mean by "closed universe"? Please, define the term.

By "closed universe", I meant a universe that doesn't have any interference from something outside itself (i.e., God).  But if we assume that, it seems more like asking, "Given the universe at time X, assuming no outside interference, are all subsequent events determined?"  But if we phrase it that way, I'm not sure what bearing the First Cause argument would have, since it seems like the cause of X, or even the existence of a cause of X, would be made irrelevant by the scope of the question rephrased in this way.

@PeterRankin In my view, the argument basically says "Our world is just one long chain of falling domino. And we know that anything in our universe must be caused. Then there is something outside our world, something supernatural, which caused the very first domino to fall". Under such view, it seems natural that without additional divine intervention "domino" will continue falling in the way they were set to fall, i.e. determinism.

Oh, I think I see what you mean.  I believe the First Cause argument is more about logical priority, rather than chronological priority, if I understand it correctly.  I.e., it's not arguing that the whole show started by a single domino falling, but that the whole show was set up by a single Person.  That person may have set off the show with many starting dominoes, and may set off additional dominoes all throughout the show.  But I'd also grant that the First Cause argument is compatible with a kind of local determinism if assuming deism (though I don't believe in that).

God is not "determined": he is the creator of laws. And also free will is created by god.

@MauroALLEGRANZA I don't say that God is determined. We just ignore God here when deciding if everything is determined or not. In-universe determinism, you could say. "And also free will is created by god." In your religious doctrine maybe, but in this specific scenario that I presented there are serious doubts about this. Although free will can be still salvaged if we adopt compatibilsm.

@MauroALLEGRANZA I edited my question, as not to cause confusion that you experienced.

It doesn't matter how the Big Bang was initiated, accidentally or deliberately. Whatever the first cause may be, it cannot determine all the future events. The complexity and entropy of the Universe cannot increase without random evolution or ongoing divine design. You are begging the question by assuming determinism and then asking if it implies determinism.

I think you have the direction of causality wrong. One can accept that every effect must have a cause, but not that every cause must lead to a determined set of effects. There can be a single chain of causality going backwards with out having it being determined going forward.

@TheDarkCanuck Let me illustrate your thought. Like suppose God created a person with free will. The person exercised their free will by baking a cake. God caused the person, the person caused the cake, thus we have our single chain of casualty tracing back to God. But given that the person has free will, his choice to bake the cake was indeterminate. Meaning that the person was a cause without determinate effects. Did I get it right?

@KarmaPeasant Yes, I think so. Even leaving free will out of it, let's say we have an alarm that goes off based on the decay of a radioactive particle. If the alarm goes off at time T, it was caused by the particle decaying. If it does not, this is also caused by the particle not decaying. But (assuming the decay is really random and not deterministic somewhere "under the hood") it could go off or not go off at any particular instant in the future (assuming it hasn't already, etc). Looking backwards, we have a determined chain, but going forwards we do not.

No. Aquinas himself was not a determinist (or fatalist, as it was called then) and not just because he believed in divine interventions. His view of human free will required indeterminism and he even adopted a peculiar interpretation of God's omniscience to reconcile it with free will, the so-called Boethian eternity solution. God is timeless, has no beliefs in time, and all temporal events are before his mind at once. His timeless knowledge does not preclude human choices in time from being indeterminate.

The Argument
I'll take the argument as presented in Wikipedia (which is a rather poor representation, but we have to start somewhere):

In the world, we can see that things are caused. But it is not possible for something to be the cause of itself because this would entail that it exists prior to itself, which is a contradiction. If that by which it is caused is itself caused, then it too must have a cause. But this cannot be an infinitely long chain, so, there must be a cause which is not itself caused by anything further. This everyone understands to be God.


Things (entities) are caused.
No thing can be a cause of itself.
Subargument (by implicit reductio ad absurdum):

if x is a cause of y then x exists before y started to exist
if x is the cause of itself, then x existed before x started to exist; but this is absurd
so, for any x, x can not be the cause of x


There is (or can be) no infinite sequence of causes leading backwards into the past.

It's not completely clear what 'thing' is supposed to mean, but we can probably assume that those who propose the argument do mean to refer to concrete physical objects -- any physical entities -- as 'caused'. There may then be an implicit assumption that each of those entities came into existence at some point in time.
In a rather different variant of the argument (which may be closer to Artistotle's First Unmoved Mover one, before Christian interpretations suppressed this aspect), certain objects, such as the stars might be considered to be eternally existing. The question then was rather, what caused the movement of those stars. (So a 'cause' would apply to either an event or a perceived pattern of events, not to an object.) In an Aristotelian view of the world that eternal movement could (I assume) also not be self-caused. I'll ignore that variant here.
The concept of 'causality' here is (by explicit assumption) temporal causality: 'causes' precede their 'effects'. (As an aside: This is the folk-philosophical concept of cause. "Where there is smoke, there is fire." "First there is a seed, then there is a tree." It is not at all the concept of causality used in modern physics. Also, a philosopher in Hume's tradition will regard the concept of temporal causality as a useless superstition.)
Another assumption is that any entity will ultimately have one definite cause. The argument relies on a claim like

For each entity x, that came into existence at time t1, there is one and only one other entity y, that was in existence at a time t0 (t0 < t1), and that 'caused' x to come into existence. This entity y will be called "the cause of x".

This does not preclude some intermediate sequence between y and x, but the argument does need the claim that any intermediate sequence (or any set of multiple causes that together caused x) ultimately leads back to one other particular cause y. Otherwise, multiple "First Movers"/"Uncaused causes" would be possible.
Is it a form of determinism? Yes
Every claim in this argument can be (and has been) disputed. If we do accept it, however, it would seem that we accept there is one particular, unique uncaused cause, TUC (The Uncaused Cause). By the argument, TUC causes everything else to come into existence, either directly or by causing a sequence of causes that causes the entity in question to come into existence.
In other words, the existence (coming into existence) of any entity (that is not identical to TUC) depends on either one sequence or perhaps multiple, simultaneous sequences of 'causes' that all lead back to UC. So, this is by definition, a form of causal determinism. By the argument, the coming into existence of any entity x can only be explained by it's sequence of causes, it fully depends on them, in other words, it is causally determined by them.

Note that talk about 'objects' and talk about 'events' sometimes blend over in eachother. I'm aware that I'm doing this here too. But I think that's mostly harmless -- at least as far as the above conclusion is concerned! One could say that the event 'x comes into being at time t1' (E1) is caused by some some other event E2 that happened before t1. But if E2 is an empirical event, it will need to refer to one or more physical objects, so, in a loose way of speaking those objects could then be called the cause(s) of x. The whole argument could also be reformulated in terms of events, rather than objects. Same conclusion would still apply.

Note also that claim (3) in this form of the argument (and I think in any variant) rules out any kind of "supernatural" first cause. Of course everyone is free to come up with any interpretation they want, but the whole point of claim (3) is to stay in our common empirical world. However, this does imply that TUC itself is either  eternal (at least up to the first act of causing something else to come into being) or somehow outside of time. If outside of time, then the argument might become incoherent (unless reformulated in terms of events rather than objects). (But note that in some interpretations it's also incorrect to see the Big Bang as an event. It's definitely not an event in time, like any other events.) Another point is that the way TUC causes something else to come into being is difficult to understand. E.g. Aristotles First Mover moves be being loved, not by pushing other things:

But since what is moved and moves something is something medial, there is something that moves without being moved, being eternal, substance, and activity. This, though, is the way the object of desire and the intelligible object move things: they move them without being moved. Of these objects, the primary ones are the same. (Metaphysics 1072a21–27)


Final note. It doesn't matter what else you believe or accept. If you accept this argument, you accept some form of causal determinism.
Traditionally (for instance in Thomist philosophy) the Christian God may have been identified with TUC, but I don't see an obvious logical contradiction between the premisses and conclusions of this argument and believing that God is not identical with TUC. It's also possible to have an interpretation of "God" or of "God created the world" which doesn't have any implications about physical science and doesn't presuppose particular empirical facts. "God created the world" could for instance mostly be meant as an emotive exclamation: "Isn't the world mysterious and wonderful!" Religious talk is not science. Faith in God does not have to mean a conceptual belief that some "supernatural" entity exists in some supernatural realm. (In fact, having such a form of belief will be regarded by many Christian theologians as a childish and immature form of faith.)
Divertissemento (Zhuang-zi)
Zhuang-zi, the Chinese philosopher (4th/3d century BC) who was the first (attested) person to ever ask why the sky is blue (and to offer two possible empirical hypotheses about it), wondered how we can ever determine when something begins (or ends):
雖然，請嘗言之。有始也者，有未始有始也者，有未始有夫未始有始也者。有有也者，有無也者，有未始有無也者，有未始有夫未始有無也者。俄而有無矣，而未知有無之果孰有孰無也。今我則已有謂矣，而未知吾所謂之其果有謂乎，其果無謂乎？
(https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=en&id=2728)
My translation:

However, let me try saying something:

There is a beginning
There is a not yet having begun to be a beginning
There is a not yet having begun to not yet having begun to be a beginning
There is being there
There is not being there
There is not yet having begun to not being there
There is not yet having begun to not yet having begun to not being there

Suddenly there is not being there, but I do not (can not) know, (in regards to) there being not being, whether there actual is being (presence) or non-being (absence). Now, I may have seemed to have said something, but I do not (can not) know if what I said actually said something or not.


"a philosopher in Hume's tradition will regard the concept of temporal causality as a useless superstition." Why?

In the context of Hume's philosophy this is basically because of the problem of induction: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/induction-problem/#LiviInduSkep
Hume himself might never call believing in temporal causes 'useless', but some philosophers in this tradition have explicitly done so (in the context of applying 'causal' arguments to decision problems for instance).

See in particular also Wittgenstein's Tractatus (W. was not a Humean, but some of his statements are consistent with Hume's skepticism):

5.134 - From an elementary proposition no other can be inferred.
5.135 - In no way can an inference be made from the existence of one state of affairs to the existence of another entirely different from it.
5.136 - There is no causal nexus which justifies such an inference.
5.1361 - The events of the future cannot be inferred from those of the present.
Superstition is the belief in the causal nexus.


Note that even Wittgenstein does not escape muddling the issue a little, by speaking of 'facts' (inference from one fact to another fact) and 'events' (inferring future events) in one breath. Also his argument is rather metaphycal, since 'elementary facts' are just as chimaerical as 'first causes'. 'Elementary facts' are an idealized abstraction that is pretty useless (and plays no role) in actual physics (or empirical science in general). But his points are still worth thinking about... :)

I think it would imply that, with a couple of qualifications; we could formulate the argument this way:

All events in the universe ultimately trace back to a single First Cause (God).
God did not create any indeterminate creatures (i.e., no truly free will).
God does not work in nature after it's initial creation (deism).
Nature is inherently deterministic.
Therefore, all of history in the universe after creation is determined.

As a Christian, I very much disagree with premises #2 and #3.  Some secular philosophers may disagree with #4, though I agree with that one.  But if starting with those premises, then it seems to me that the conclusion would logically follow.

Good point, but this is not what I wanted. Seems like I missed a hidden premise in my thinking. I will add it.

I clarified my question

Thanks, I've rewritten my answer to address the clarified question.

Probably we could have said "God did not DIRECTLY create any indeterminate creatures". Theoretically, we are open to possibility that somehow the chain of events which started with the Big Bang led to emergence of creatures that ARE indeterminate, although this would look strange, as they are basically machines without souls (as God didn't directly give them any souls) or anything like this that might have caused them to behave differently from any matter in the Universe.

Hmm, probably we should reject possibility of natural emergence of  indeterminate creatures when Nature is deterministic. It would be very strange for deterministic processes creating anything indeterminate.

Yeah, I would agree that if chemicals are determinate, anything built with chemicals alone must also be determinate, even if unpredictably complex.

Hmm ... If #1 is true, then can #2 be false? Like suppose God created a person with free will. The person exercised their free will by baking a cake.  Was the cake caused by God? On one hand, if God didn't create the person, then this specific cake would have never existed. On the other hand, if baking the cake was indeterminate choice, then can we really say that the cake was caused by anything other than the person? And if God is still a cause for the cake, then how is this person different from a person without free will?

Interesting question...I'd say yes, because (1) God created the ability of the will to choose; (2) God created the baker's faculties to enforce the choice; (3) God ultimately created all the cake ingredients; and, biblically, (4) God chooses to allow each free choice that is carried out.  And so God is the necessary, ultimate, and first cause of the cake, just not the sole or direct determinative cause, is how I'd probably put it.  But a created indeterminate free will is certainly different than other mediate causes, in a class all of its own!

The argument establishes only that for every causal chain of events there must have been a first cause that started the chain. However, nothing supports the assumption that this first cause is God.
The current scientific consensus is that the very first event, called the Big Bang, was an uncaused event. There is no time before it and therefore no prior cause.
The first cause of a causal chain does not necessarily have to be an event. It can also be a deliberate decision by a conscious being. Therefore God's decision to create the Universe is still a valid, although unsupported, alternative to Big Bang.
None of this implies determinism. In determinism there are no uncaused events or deliberate decisions. No Big Bang, no evolution. No God, no creation.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
